# Angular 2 binding/events not working when adding template as innerHTML

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I am trying to create a reusable table which can be configurable. The cells can be configured to have html template.

I am configuring the column "**Review**" to have html template with anchor tag with click event (review(row)).

So far I tried to insert this template as innerHTML, but then none of the angular binding works. Then I tried to create a dynamically invoked component (review.component.ts) but this component invoked only once for first row. Moreover I didn't find any way to pass the current row item to click event review(row) (inside review.component.ts).

**employee.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef, Inject, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import {Router, RouteConfig, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {DataTableComponent} from '../../data_table/data_table.component';
import {DataTable} from '../../data_table/dataTable';
import {Cell} from '../../data_table/cell';
import {ReviewComponent} from './review.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'employee',
    templateUrl: './app/employee/employee.html',
    directives: [DataTableComponent, ReviewComponent, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
    public tableConfig: DataTable;
    public constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private elementRef: ElementRef, private injector: Injector) {
        this.tableConfig = new DataTable();
        this.tableConfig.rows = [{ Sr: 1, Name: 'saurabh' }, { Sr: 2, Name: 'arun' }];
        var cellSr = new Cell();
        var cellName = new Cell();
        var cellReview = new Cell();
        cellSr.name = 'Sr';
        cellName.name = 'Name';

        //setting innerHtml directly doesn't work. Any way to make the bindings work in such case?
        //cellReview.innerHtml='<a class="btn btn-default" (click)="review(row)">Review</a>'

        cellReview.innerHtml = '<div class="child"></div>';
        this.tableConfig.cells = [cellSr, cellName, cellReview];
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.dcl.loadAsRoot(ReviewComponent, '.child', this.injector);
    }
}
```

**review.component.ts:**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import {Router, RouteConfig, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

@Component({
    selector: 'btn-review',
    template: `<a class="btn btn-default" (click)="review(row)">Review</a>`,
    directives: [RouterLink, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

export class ReviewComponent {
    constructor() {}
    public review(event){
        console.log(event);
        console.log(2);
    }
 }
```

**datatable.ts:**

```
import {Cell} from './cell';
export class DataTable {
    rows: Array<any>;
    cells: Cell[];
}
```

**data_table.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import {Router, RouteConfig, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {TAB_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import {DataTable} from './dataTable';
import {Cell} from './cell';
@Component({
    selector: 'data-table',
    templateUrl: './data_table/data_table.html',
    directives: [RouterLink, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
export class DataTableComponent {
    @Input() dataTable: DataTable;   
    bindCell(cell: Cell, row: any) {
        var text = '';
        if (cell.innerHtml && cell.innerHtml.length > 0) {
            return cell.innerHtml;
        }
    }   
}
```

**data_table.html:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of dataTable.rows">
            <td *ngFor="let cell of dataTable.cells" [innerHTML]="bindCell(cell, row)">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This might be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular doesn't process HTML added using `innerHtml` (also  `ElementRef.nativeElement.append(...)` or similar) in any way.

As mentioned in the comment an alternative is to wrap the HTML in a component and add this component dynamically. `DynamicComponentLoader` (as shown in the linked answer from the comment to your question) is deprecated. It was replaced by `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`. [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) shows an example how to use it.