# Angular 6 Directive that injects HTML dynamically

Tags: html, angular

I'm using a directive to inject HTML dynamically to other HTML elements, specifically to other components in which i can't modify the code.
My issue is that if i inject HTML elements in which they call a local function from the same component they don't work.
An example of this:

```
<button class="button-default" (click)="showTable()">Show table info</button>
```

In this case, doesn't happen nothing if you press the button, the function is not called.

The directive code:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef,AfterViewInit, Input} from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
    selector: '[insertHtml]'
})

export class InsertHtml {

    @Input()   targetHtml : string;
    @Input()   html : string;
    @Input()   position: any;

    private el: HTMLInputElement;
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { 
        this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;  

    }



  ngAfterViewInit() {

        let target = this.el.querySelector(this.targetHtml );
        target.insertAdjacentHTML(this.position, this.html);

    }
}
```

How it works the directive:

```
<div class="block" [insertHtml]="'ul.nav.nav-tabs'" [html]="htmlButtons" [position]="'afterend'">
```

htmlButtons would be code i put in the example case.

How i can make the function inside of the injected HTML elements work?

Comment: please show a full picture how the method and the containing component and directives are laid out in your code? Or better make a reproduction. Thanks

Comment: You may find ideas in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41609937/1009922).

Comment: @ConnorsFan Looks like a workaround but i take it

Comment: I think only workarounds can work, as mentioned in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37936094/1009922).

Comment: @ConnorsFan what about if i need to use *ngIf ,ngClass or similar directives?

Comment: If you avoid inserting the HTML directly, but use Angular structural directives (`ngIf`, `ngFor`), templates or components instead, event binding should work, yes. These are the way to work with Angular.