# Binding input element through innerHtml with [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6, angular-dynamic-components

I have a component ts file like below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  

@Component({
  template: '<div [innerHtml]='htmlContent'></div>'
})

export class DesignComponent implements OnInit {

modelValue='abcd';

htmlContent='<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="modelValue" name="model"> ';

constructor(){}

}
```

In my template, I am inserting html using innerHtml method like below

```
<div [innerHtml]='htmlContent'></div>
```

So, it is displaying output as input box, but ngModel values not rendering into the input box.

I tried using sanitize also, Still model value not inserting into input box.

Sanitize tried in 2 ways like,

```
this.htmlContent= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlContent);
this.htmlContent= this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, htmlContent);
```

How to achieve this using angular2/4/5?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 binding/events not working when adding template as innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901436/angular-2-binding-events-not-working-when-adding-template-as-innerhtml)

Comment: @saran why you use [innerHTML] instead of doing in a simple way... ?

Comment: @saran Are you able to view text box in HTML page ?

Comment: I am able to see text box, but i can't edit the text box, that's a different problem

Comment: @saran Till I have tried in my experience If you will set form then also you will not be able to get button click event ... I think you should think some other option. If you can show how you got data from backend then I can help you ...

Comment: @Sachin, After service call i'm getting bunch of html code which contains images, div, input boxes with values and models , user can edit the page and he can save that as a new page with new value, this process will continue many time, so dynamic html code i can't write directly in template, so through some way i have to render it.

Comment: did you get the answer of your question?